# Django, How can i use {% url %} template in jQuery, prepend?

Tags: jquery, django

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) { #Here is where 'value' from
    $("#contentsbox")
        .prepend(
            '<div><a id="URLcomes" href="{% url 'somename' value.id %}">Here comes hyperlinks</a></div>'
        );
});
```

I've got some json data and want to make `div` tag dynamically.

I will use .prepend() but there needs plain text and i can't make string with `{% url 'somename' value.id %}`

At that template tag, value.id is from `each` - function(index, `value`)

I want `{% url 'somename' value.id %}` in prepend(), but I can't make it string as `prepend()` needs.

How can i make string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, 
Inside your html, put

```
<div id="element-id" url="{% url 'somename' value.id %}" style="display : none;"></div>
```

before the scripts.
Inside your jquery,

```
var str = $('#element-id').attr('url');
//str will give you the desired string.
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.